# Programmatically generate HTML for HitHighlightedSummary using KeywordQuery in FAST search for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch, keywordquery

I am trying to develop a customized SharePoint 2010 web part for FAST search.  I am using `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery` something like this:

```
var FASTquery = new KeywordQuery(proxy)
{
    ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.FASTSearch,
    QueryText = queryText,
    ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults | ResultType.RefinementResults
};
FASTquery.SelectProperties.AddRange(
    new string[] { "Title", /* ..., */ "HitHighlightedSummary" });
ResultTableCollection searchResults = FASTquery.Execute();
```

I go on to bind `searchResults[ResultType.RelevantResults]` to a `Repeater` control.  I'm trying to get the "hit highlighted summary" to appear by calling [`FASTquery.HighlightStringValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.highlightstringvalue.aspx).  The value I'm passing is the `HitHighlightedSummary` from `searchResults`.  An example of what this looks like for a result when searching for "ear" is:

```
<ddd/>FALSE ); GetDlgItem(IDC_<c0>EAR</c0>_PAIN_STATIC)-&gt;EnableWindow<ddd/>FALSE ); GetDlgIte(IDC_<c0>EAR</c0>_PAIN_ABSENT_RADIO<ddd/>FALSE ); GetDlgItem(IDC_<c0>EAR</c0>_PAIN_MILD_RADIO<ddd/>
```

However, when called with a string like this, `FASTquery.HighlightStringValue()` is throwing a `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` with the message "Value does not fall within the expected range."

What is the correct way to convert this excerpt to HTML, or should I be calling `HighlightStringValue()` with some other value?  The documentation is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Please share the code for your call to FASTquery.HighlightStringValue()

Answer (score 8):

I typically perform a manual conversion of the hit highlighted summary markup to HTML. You'll find a combination of two markers in the summary:

- <c0> </c0> (Highlight)
- <ddd/> (Ellipsis)

A manual transformation of the markup could be as simple as the following string replacement:

```
string hitHighilghtedSummary;
// ...

hitHighlightedSummary = hitHighlightedSummary.Replace("c0", "strong").Replace("<ddd/>", "&#8230;");
```